# PrimeFaces. Как получить в java значение выбранного элемента panelmenu

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Добрый день. Я создаю меню на основе выборки из БД и panelMenu. Мне необходимо передать в мой managed bean значение выбранного пункта меню, но не пойму как...

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли такая возможность?

Java code:

```
@PostConstruct
    public void getTestMenu() {
       ...
                for (Iterator it3 = this.testList.iterator(); it3.hasNext();) {
                    Test t = (Test) it3.next();
                    DefaultMenuItem dsmBuffItem = new DefaultMenuItem(t.getIdz());
                    dsmBuffItem.setId(String.valueOf(t.getIdz()));
                    dsmBuffSecond.addElement(dsmBuffItem);
                }
                dsmBuffFirst.addElement(dsmBuffSecond);
            }
            this.menuModel.addElement(dsmBuffFirst);

        }
    }
```

xhtm code:

```
<h:body>
            <h:form>
                <p:layout fullPage="true">
                    <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="false"  minSize="240" >
                        <p:panelMenu id="Test" model="#{testController.menuModel}"  />
                    </p:layoutUnit>

                    ...
                </p:layout>

            </h:form>
     </h:body>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наверное к menuitem-мам надо привязать action или listener. action можно сделать с параметром, в качестве параметра можно использовать тот же menuitem. У listener есть стандартный параметр из которого можно извлечь menuitem, но можно сделать и со своим параметром подобно action. Посмотрите как делаются programatic menu здесь http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menu.xhtml правда там без параметров, но ничто не мешает додумать с параметром, если приспичит

Comment: @Sergey Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void getTestMenu() {
...
    dsmBuffItem.setCommand("#{testController.callTest}");
    dsmBuffItem.setParam("myId", t.getIdz());
...
}

public void callTest(ActionEvent event) {
    MenuItem menuItem = ((MenuActionEvent) event).getMenuItem();
    Long id = Long.parseLong(menuItem.getParams().get("myId").get(0));

    System.out.println(id);
}
```

При формировании меню указываем имя метода, который следует вызвать в `setCommand`, и параметр, который следует передать методу в `setParam`. В вызываемом методе извлекаем искомый параметр из объекта события.

Comment: Может быть так. Сомнения относительно того, что callTest у Вас это actionListener, хотя в примере простой метод без параметра, т.е. action . К сожалению в мануале и даже в javadoc нет разъяснения что может быть помещено в setCommand().

Comment: @Sergey, можете не сомневаться в корректности приведённого кода, т.к. я протестировал его работоспособность перед публикацией ответа. В тестовом проекте использовалась версия Primefaces 5.3.

Comment: добрый день! Спасибо за помощь. Всё заработало в лучшем виде.

Comment: Ещё одни вопрос. Я новичок в PrimeFaces и хотел узнать есть ли где-то инфа о правилах использования ActionEvent, SelectEvent, когда нужно пользоваться dsmBuffItem.setParam(), а когда setValue(). Вообще документация по использованию Java API PF. А то многие моменты совсем не понятны :(

Comment: Можно почерпнуть множество практических примеров из http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/